# Using libunwind in a shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stack-unwinding

I want to provide a generic call stack function as part of a library (.so) using `libunwind`. However, executables linked against the .so start to fail as soon as I link against `libunwind`. As I understand it, the problem I'm running into is that `libunwind` defines the same symbols as the GCC runtime, but the implementation is seemingly not compatible.

Linking statically or dynamically against `libunwind` doesn't change anything, I get a segfault when throwing an exception in `_Unwind_Resume` (if linked statically), otherwise the call-stack starts at `__cxa_throw` (presumably, it has been damaged before.)

Interestingly, the problems only occur when I use GCC, with Clang, everything works just fine.

Is it possible to use `libunwind` inside a shared library? If not, is there another library which allows me to obtained the name plus instruction pointer offset of the functions on the stack? `backtrace()` is nearly good enough, but `backtrace_symbols()` is doing too much formatting which I would have to "un-parse" first.

Comment: It appears to work fine in my case. I am using gcc-4.8.2 and libunwind8. Could you post some code?

Comment: That's the problem, it only fails in the larger application. I couldn't get it to repro in a small case; might be also related to visibility setting.

Comment: I haven't had an issue doing this, either. A small reproducer would be helpful.